# Better way to check for file type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For an app which uses a directory walker I need the information if a file is accessible, a real file and need to distinguish between file and directory entries.

I want to:

- skip all soft-links, pipes and other special files.
- only access files which can be read and could be written to.
- only list directories which can be entered and listed.

So all files can be read and could be manipulated and reside in directories which allow that.

This is what I came up with:

```
fileType :: FilePath -> IO Int
fileType f = do
    -- skip any symbolic link
    l <- getSymbolicLinkStatus f
    if isSymbolicLink l
        then return 0 -- link
        else do
            s <- getFileStatus f
            if isRegularFile s
                then do
                    -- files need read and write
                    facc <- fileAccess f True True False
                    if facc
                        then return 1
                        else return 0 -- file but not RW
                else if isDirectory s
                    then do
                        -- dirs need read and execute
                        dacc <- fileAccess f True False True
                        if dacc
                            then return 2
                            else return 0 -- dir but not RX
                    else return 0 -- not a file or dir
```

But I am pretty unsure about the implementation and want to ask if there is something I could do to make this more concise.

For example I have a feeling that I could at least move "return" somewhere at the top. But trying this I could not get the types right.

P.S.: It is fine for me to return Int 0 1 2 (instead of a special datatype) but I don't mind if that is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the other answers and comments (many thanks!) I want to answer my own question and show you what I was coming up with:

```
data FileType = Skip | File | Dir

getFileType :: FilePath -> IO FileType
getFileType f = getSymbolicLinkStatus f >>= testIt
    where testIt s
            | isSymbolicLink s = return Skip
            | isRegularFile s = useWhen (fileAccess f True True False) File
            | isDirectory s = useWhen (fileAccess f True False True) Dir
            | otherwise = return Skip

          useWhen p t = p >>= \b -> if b then return t else return Skip
```

What I did was:

- First creating the type I really needed (Skip, File, Dir).
- Then I found that I really just need to get the fileStatus once (and this should not follow a symbolic link).
- After this it was trivial to see that this ends up with multiple cases and I used guards for that.
- While trying "ifM" (bdef from the comment) I saw that the universal form is just to universal 8now) but it is nice to have a helper to make the function more readable.
- ifM actually is more something like "when" in that case.
- Removing do with bind in some places because do had only one action left.

Comment: That did turn out quite pretty! I'll note that `useWhen p t` can also be written in "applicative style" as `bool Skip t <$> p` with the functions `Data.Bool.bool` and `Data.Functor.<$>`.

Comment: Hm although I guessed wrong on the argument order of `bool` and had to edit... maybe that function is too confusing. :(

Comment: I think whoever added the `bool` function chose a really confusing argument order.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Int` to keep track of the different file type, you can use the sum type to denote different file type:

```
data FileType = SymbolicLink  -- Symbolic link
              | FileRead      -- File with Read Permission
              | DirRead       -- Directory with Read Permission
              | DirNoRead     -- Directory with No Read Permission
              | FileNoRead    -- File with No Read Permssion
              | NotFileAndDir -- Neither File nor directory
              deriving (Show)
```

One pattern which I can see in your code is that there are various nested monadic if to check conditions and then return an appropriate result based on that. You can see if the standard library offers such a abstraction or if it doesn't you can write it for yourself:

```
bdef :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
bdef mb t f  = mb >>= \x -> if x then t else f
```

In the `bdef` function, in case if `mb` is `IO True`, then I'm returing the first parameter or else the second parameter. Note that it doesn't need to be `IO` but it can be any monad. Once this is defined, the rest is to define the remaining function:

```
filetype :: FilePath -> IO FileType
filetype f =  sym
  where sym = bdef (isSymbolicLink <$> getSymbolicLinkStatus f)
                (return SymbolicLink) reg
        reg = bdef (isRegularFile <$> fStatus)
              (bdef checkfRead (return FileRead) (return FileNoRead)) dir
        dir = bdef (isDirectory <$> fStatus)
              (bdef checkDRead (return DirRead) (return DirNoRead))
              (return NotFileAndDir)
        checkfRead = fileAccess f True True False
        checkDRead = fileAccess f True False True
        fStatus = getFileStatus f
```

Sample `ghci` demo:

```
λ> filetype "/home/sibi/test.hs"
FileRead
λ> filetype "/home/sibi"
DirRead
```

Comment: You can also remove the argument `f` from `sym,reg,dir`. Further, note that this runs `getFileStatus` twice, while the OP code ran it only once. (Not a big deal, IMHO, but a minor difference.)

Comment: @chi Made changes to remove `f` and also added your suggested optimization. :)

Comment: This will *still* run `getFileStatus` twice; you are renaming the action to `fStatus` but it's still an `IO` action in each place, not any shared result.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yes... Forgot that it was an `IO` action.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! It gave me some ideas to come up with the new version I just posted below.